How can I automate retrieving the GCP application default credentials from the terraform vault?
I am trying to supply the GCP application credentials to terraform via the HashiCorp vault. I have managed to do it by first executing gcloud auth application-default login, but I would like to automate the process. Details below.

I have stored to the HashiCorp vault an app_credentials.json file, which has the GCP Application Credentials. I have the following provider setup, based on this thread:
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "my-terraform-bucket "
    prefix = "terraform/state"
  }
}

provider "vault" {
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "credentials" {
  path = "gcp-credentials"
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = data.vault_generic_secret.credentials.data["app_credentials.json"]
}

However, terraform refuses to retrieve the credentials from the vault. I receive the following error:
~$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...
Initializing modules...
╷
│ Error: storage.NewClient() failed: dialing: google: could not find default credentials. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information

I can work around this problem by either:

Executing gcloud auth application-default login based on this response; or
copying the app_credentials.json to the local filesystem and setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, per this suggestion.

However, I am looking for an automated way to retrieve the credentials from the vault without needing to run gcloud or keep a local credentials file.

storage.NewClient() is failing because it's unable to find application default credentials to authenticate the request. You won't be able to use any Google services without authentication to retrieve another set of credentials.

In principle securing credentials in a secret store (as long as this really is more secure) is going to be better than leaving credentials on a host. However, you may be better placed focusing on the use of Service Accounts and Workload Identity Federation (if you can).

You shouldn't be trying to persist credentials created by gcloud auth application-default in a secret store.

Using Vault with Terraform for authentication in provider blocks generally requires a wrapper. Using a data will not work. Possibly the Vault provider could implement a function for >= 1.8 that supplies the credentials to the provider earlier.
